# Fetching from AWS Lambda retrieves old data

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a serverless-based, isomorphic next.js app that fetches data from a CDN that it uses to render the website. It does this by what I might've thought was a fairly innocuous method:

```
const data = d3.csv(`https://cdn.example.com/data/my_data.csv?time=${Date.now()}`);
```

This retrieves the data nicely enough, but it retrieves stale data—at times many hours old. The same code, when it runs on the client side, happily fetches up-to-date data.

Relevant other information:

- This happens on a number of computers (and I have caching disabled on my development browser) so it's not a local browser issue.
- I do not have the site itself behind a CDN, and the data file's CDN updates fairly quickly (when I navigate to the file directly, I see the most recent update, and the client-side version has no problem accessing the newer file).
- I have added a (theoretically) cache-busting query string to no avail.
- I have gone so far as to *remove and redeploy the entire app*, and I still see the stale data.

Why is this happening, and more importantly: how can I get AWS Lambda to see current copies of the data file?

Comment: The data that you're trying to extract via fetch, is it behind a CDN or not? (wasn't clear from the explanation). Please note that CDNs apply caching as well. If the data is behind a CDN, you may just need to flush the cache on the CDN (via the CDNs settings).

Comment: Is `const data = ...` inside your handler function, or is it global?

Comment: `const data` is inside the handler function. Also, even if it were something global, surely deleting and redeploying the app clears even global variables?

Comment: to isolate the issue, can you log the content of `data` in cloudwatch? and see if the result is always the same even when the new data is available? And probably log the url itself (with the time query)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestion comes to mind:

- As it is currently stated, the `Date.now()` function is never executed, c.f. the output of  `...time=${Date.now}` vs `...time=${Date.now()}`
- What is the expected format of the `time` parameter? According to the documentation, the [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) function

  > returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC

Comment: Sorry, I mistranscribed the code—it uses Date.now(). I’ll update. The parameter isn’t used, it is just there to ensure the URL is always unique.